# How to fix mistakes with reading json file, python3.7

Tags: python, json, ubuntu

my json file - `{"_id": "bc903ddd-90dd-4bff-b711-97dee4cce13c", "cefVersion": 0, "deviceVendor": "Custom Vendor", "deviceProduct": "Statistic", "deviceVersion": "", "deviceEventClassId": "statistic", "name": "Feature extracting (1 level)", "severity": "Normal", "extensions": {"subject": "grigoreva-d@gaz-is.ru", "features": [{"key": "tgt_count", "value": 0.026112756936360167, "absolute_value": 81, "label": "Количество полученных сообщений", "description": "Количество полученных сообщений (количество событий, в которых пользователь фигурирует как получатель)"}, {"key": "src_count", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество отправленных сообщений", "description": "Количество отправлений (количество событий, в которых пользователь фигурирует как отправитель)"}, {"key": "self_count", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество отправленных сообщений себе", "description": "Количество сообщений, отправленных пользователем самому себе"}, {"key": "total_count", "value": 0.026112756936360167, "absolute_value": 81, "label": "Общее количество сообщений", "description": "Общее количество сообщений"}, {"key": "mass_send_count", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество массовых отправлений", "description": "Количество массовых отправлений"}, {"key": "mass_recept_count", "value": 0.010316150888438584, "absolute_value": 32, "label": "Количество массовых получений", "description": "Количество сообщений, полученных пользователем, которые классифицируются как массовые"}, {"key": "tgt_addr_uniq", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество уникальных получателей ", "description": "Количество уникальных получателей (адресов), которым пользователь отправлял сообщения"}, {"key": "src_addr_uniq", "value": 0.0022566580068459404, "absolute_value": 7, "label": "Количество уникальных отправителей ", "description": "Количество уникальных отправителей (адресов) с которых пользователю поступали e-mail"}, {"key": "src_part_internal", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество внутренних отправлений", "description": "Количество сообщений, отправленных пользователем, которые классифицируются как внутренние. Из [@gaz-is.ru]"}, {"key": "src_part_external", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество внешних отправлений", "description": "Количество сообщений, отправленных пользователем, которые классифицируются как внешние. Не из [@gaz-is.ru]"}, {"key": "src_part_custom", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество отправлений на @gaz-i.ru", "description": "Количество сообщений, отправленных пользователем в адресаты заданного домена (группы доменов). Из [@gmail.com, @mail.ru]"}, {"key": "tgt_part_internal", "value": 0.026112756936360167, "absolute_value": 81, "label": "Количество отправлений на @gaz-is.ru", "description": "Количество сообщений, полученных пользователем, которые классифицируются как внутренние. Из [@gaz-is.ru]"}, {"key": "tgt_part_external", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество полученных сообщений не из @gaz-is.ru", "description": "Количество сообщений, полученных пользователем, которые классифицируются как внешние. Не из [@gaz-is.ru]"}, {"key": "tgt_part_custom", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество полученных сообщений из @gmail.com, @mail.ru", "description": "Количество сообщений, полученных пользователем от заданного домена (группы доменов). Из [@gmail.com, @mail.ru]"}], "features_auxiliary": [{"key": "norm_coefficient", "value": 3101.932139812217, "label": "Нормирующий коэффициент", "description": "Нормирующий коэффициент"}, {"key": "day_name", "value": "Monday", "label": "День", "description": "День недели (название)"}, {"key": "year", "value": 2020, "label": "Год", "description": "Год"}, {"key": "month", "value": 8, "label": "Месяц", "description": "Месяц"}, {"key": "day_of_month", "value": 3, "label": "День месяца", "description": "День (номер дня в месяце)"}, {"key": "day_of_year", "value": 216, "label": "День года", "description": "День (номер дня в году)"}, {"key": "hour", "value": 11, "label": "Час", "description": "Час"}, {"key": "minute", "value": 0, "label": "Минута", "description": "Минута"}, {"key": "is_holiday", "value": false, "label": "Праздник", "description": "Признак праздничного дня"}, {"key": "is_weekday", "value": false, "label": "Выходной", "description": "Признак выходного дня"}, {"key": "count_agg", "value": 356, "label": "Количество сообщений для субъекта", "description": "Количество сообщений для субъекта"}, {"key": "count_message", "value": 81, "label": "Количество обработанных сообщений для субъекта", "description": "Количество обработанных сообщений для субъекта"}, {"key": "count_message_all", "value": 3077, "label": "Количество обработанных сообщений ", "description": "Количество обработанных сообщений за 3600"}], "rt": 1596441600000, "windows_size": 3600}}`

my mistake - File "/mnt/c/python/job2/grader/src/streamers.py", line 417, in stdin_reader

```
yield json.loads(line)
```

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/**init**.py", line 348, in loads

```
return _default_decoder.decode(s)
```

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode

```
obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
```

File "/usr/lib/python3.7/json/decoder.py", line 353, in raw_decode

```
obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
```

json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 2926 (char 2925)

Answer (score 0):

You can either read json from a file or a variable directly like below:-

```
    import json
    j='{"_id": "bc903ddd-90dd-4bff-b711-97dee4cce13c", "cefVersion": 0, "deviceVendor": "Custom Vendor", "deviceProduct": "Statistic", "deviceVersion": "", "deviceEventClassId": "statistic", "name": "Feature extracting (1 level)", "severity": "Normal", "extensions": {"subject": "grigoreva-d@gaz-is.ru", "features": [{"key": "tgt_count", "value": 0.026112756936360167, "absolute_value": 81, "label": "Количество полученных сообщений", "description": "Количество полученных сообщений (количество событий, в которых пользователь фигурирует как получатель)"}, {"key": "src_count", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество отправленных сообщений", "description": "Количество отправлений (количество событий, в которых пользователь фигурирует как отправитель)"}, {"key": "self_count", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество отправленных сообщений себе", "description": "Количество сообщений, отправленных пользователем самому себе"}, {"key": "total_count", "value": 0.026112756936360167, "absolute_value": 81, "label": "Общее количество сообщений", "description": "Общее количество сообщений"}, {"key": "mass_send_count", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество массовых отправлений", "description": "Количество массовых отправлений"}, {"key": "mass_recept_count", "value": 0.010316150888438584, "absolute_value": 32, "label": "Количество массовых получений", "description": "Количество сообщений, полученных пользователем, которые классифицируются как массовые"}, {"key": "tgt_addr_uniq", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество уникальных получателей ", "description": "Количество уникальных получателей (адресов), которым пользователь отправлял сообщения"}, {"key": "src_addr_uniq", "value": 0.0022566580068459404, "absolute_value": 7, "label": "Количество уникальных отправителей ", "description": "Количество уникальных отправителей (адресов) с которых пользователю поступали e-mail"}, {"key": "src_part_internal", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество внутренних отправлений", "description": "Количество сообщений, отправленных пользователем, которые классифицируются как внутренние. Из [@gaz-is.ru]"}, {"key": "src_part_external", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество внешних отправлений", "description": "Количество сообщений, отправленных пользователем, которые классифицируются как внешние. Не из [@gaz-is.ru]"}, {"key": "src_part_custom", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество отправлений на @gaz-i.ru", "description": "Количество сообщений, отправленных пользователем в адресаты заданного домена (группы доменов). Из [@gmail.com, @mail.ru]"}, {"key": "tgt_part_internal", "value": 0.026112756936360167, "absolute_value": 81, "label": "Количество отправлений на @gaz-is.ru", "description": "Количество сообщений, полученных пользователем, которые классифицируются как внутренние. Из [@gaz-is.ru]"}, {"key": "tgt_part_external", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество полученных сообщений не из @gaz-is.ru", "description": "Количество сообщений, полученных пользователем, которые классифицируются как внешние. Не из [@gaz-is.ru]"}, {"key": "tgt_part_custom", "value": 0.0, "absolute_value": 0, "label": "Количество полученных сообщений из @gmail.com, @mail.ru", "description": "Количество сообщений, полученных пользователем от заданного домена (группы доменов). Из [@gmail.com, @mail.ru]"}], "features_auxiliary": [{"key": "norm_coefficient", "value": 3101.932139812217, "label": "Нормирующий коэффициент", "description": "Нормирующий коэффициент"}, {"key": "day_name", "value": "Monday", "label": "День", "description": "День недели (название)"}, {"key": "year", "value": 2020, "label": "Год", "description": "Год"}, {"key": "month", "value": 8, "label": "Месяц", "description": "Месяц"}, {"key": "day_of_month", "value": 3, "label": "День месяца", "description": "День (номер дня в месяце)"}, {"key": "day_of_year", "value": 216, "label": "День года", "description": "День (номер дня в году)"}, {"key": "hour", "value": 11, "label": "Час", "description": "Час"}, {"key": "minute", "value": 0, "label": "Минута", "description": "Минута"}, {"key": "is_holiday", "value": false, "label": "Праздник", "description": "Признак праздничного дня"}, {"key": "is_weekday", "value": false, "label": "Выходной", "description": "Признак выходного дня"}, {"key": "count_agg", "value": 356, "label": "Количество сообщений для субъекта", "description": "Количество сообщений для субъекта"}, {"key": "count_message", "value": 81, "label": "Количество обработанных сообщений для субъекта", "description": "Количество обработанных сообщений для субъекта"}, {"key": "count_message_all", "value": 3077, "label": "Количество обработанных сообщений ", "description": "Количество обработанных сообщений за 3600"}], "rt": 1596441600000, "windows_size": 3600}}'
    y = json.loads(j)
    print(y)
```